# Passing the current activity instance to a method

Tags: java, android

I have a button, part of whose functionality is in a class, that is in another class file in the same package. Is this the way how it is supposed to be done or I can somehow pass the instance of the current activity and then use whatever methods or fields it has in the methods of the second class.

```
public class LogInScreen extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button logInButton;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_log_in_screen);

        logInButton = findViewById(R.id.button_login);
        userText = findViewById(R.id.editText_user);
        passText = findViewById(R.id.editText_pass);
    }

    public void logIn(View view) {
        logInButton.setEnabled(false);

        String username = userText.getText().toString();
        String password = passText.getText().toString();

        BackendConnectionService.encodeCredentials(username, password);

        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        BackendConnectionService.handleSSLHandshake();
        // here I put the button
        requestQueue.add(BackendConnectionService.createLogInRequest(this, logInButton));
    }
}
```

Declaration of the second class

```
public class BackendConnectionService {
    // some class declarations


    static JsonArrayRequest createLogInRequest(Context packageContext, Button button){
        final Context context = packageContext;
        final Button b = button;
        return new JsonArrayRequest(
                Request.Method.GET,
                PALLETE_URL,
                null,
                new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(context, PalletsScreen.class);
                        context.startActivity(intent);
                        b.setEnabled(true);
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Log.e("REST ResponseErr", error.toString());
                        Toast.makeText(context, error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        b.setEnabled(true);
                    }
                }) {

            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();
                headers.put(autorisation, encodedCredentials);
                return headers;
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not a good architecture, try to revise your architecture.

Comment: @insa_c Could you give me a clue how to improve it?

Comment: You shouldn't really pass any view objects to the repository layer. Instead you need to create a callback and pass that callback to the repository.
Take a look at this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/48385867/5152910. Create callback interface in your repository, implement it in your activity class(this is where you need to change your button's attributes) and pass the callback object to your repository function.

Comment: @insa_c Actually 6 hours ago I have done exactly that and it works. Thank you for your comment.

Answer (score 1):

To be honest with you, you already did it :). You just need to know how to use it. Let's say that you want to use your LogInScreen in your `createLogInRequest` method:

```
static JsonArrayRequest createLogInRequest(Context packageContext, Button button){
    final Context context = packageContext;
    final Button b = button;

    LogInScreen logInScreen = null;
    if(context instanceof LogInScreen) {
        logInScreen = (LogInScreen) context;
    }
    //...
}
```